# using ngComponentOutlet to project content into a parent component Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I'm currently have a parent component that does somthing like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: <div><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) private childComponent: ChildComponent
  ngAfterViewInit(): void { console.log(this.childComponent.value); }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: <div>Child</div>',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  public value: string = "Hello Parent";
}
```

Is there any way I can get ngComponentOutlet to play nicely with content projection and/or @ContentChild(ren)?  As it stands it doesn't look like there is any way to get a handle to the dynamic component, nor is the parent component able to communicate with the child component in any real sense.  Any ideas?

For context, I'm trying to write a wrapper for ag-grid-angular to add additional features and one of the features that I need is to be able to dynamically add columns to the grid via ngComponentOutlet.

Comment: using `@Content...` or `@View...` queries it's impossible to get an instance of `ComponentRef` that is passed into the `ngComponentOutlet`. You should probably use `ng-template` as a projected content and then use view containerref to insert it.

Comment: The problem is that I need the users of parent component to be able to use ngComponentOutlet to put child component in

Comment: a child component can be wrapped into `ng-template` like this: `<parent-component><ng-template><child-component></child-component></ng-template></parent-component>`

Comment: That won't work for me.  I need users to be able to configure in another part of the application a component containing several other child components which can be added into the parent component via ngComponentOutlet.  Essentially there are 3 parts of this:
1.)  Library component where parent and child are defined.
2.) Skeleton component that contains parent with ngComponentOutlet inside.
3.)  User configuration where a Type is provided that will be dynamically placed via the ngComponentOutlet from step 2.